# mongoose schema transform not invoked if document is returned directly from query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an endpoint that does an operation such as this:

```
        const pipeline = [
          {
            $match: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $or: [...],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id : '$someProp',
              anotherProp: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
            },
          },
          { $sort: { date: -1 } },
          { $limit: 10 },
        ]
        const groupedDocs = await MyModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

The idea here is that the returned documents look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 'some value',
    anotherProp: [ /* ... array of documents where "someProp" === "some value" */ ],
  },
  {
    _id: 'another value',
    anotherProp: [ /* ... array of documents where "someProp" === "another value" */ ],
  },
  ...
]
```

After getting these results, the endpoint responds with an array containing all the members of `anotherProp`, like this:

```
const response = groupedDocs.reduce((docs, group) => docs.concat(group.anotherProp), []);
res.status(200).json(response);
```

My problem is that the final documents in the response contain the `_id` field, but I want to rename that field to `id`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id) addresses this issue, and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763286/7987987) is what *should* work, but for some reason the transform function doesn't get invoked. To put it differently, I've tried doing this:

```
schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
        console.log(`transforming toJSON for document ${doc._id}`);
        delete ret._id;
    },
});
schema.set('toObject', {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
        console.log(`transforming toObject for document ${doc._id}`);
        delete ret._id;
    },
});
```

But the `console.log` statements are not executed, meaning that the transform function is not getting invoked. So I still get the `_id` in the response instead of `id`.

So my question is **how can I get `id` instead of `_id` in this scenario?**

Worth mentioning that `toJSON` and `toObject` are invoked (the `console.log`s show) in other places where I read properties from the documents. Like if I do:

```
const doc = await MyModel.findById('someId');
const name = doc.name;
res.status(200).json(doc);
```

The response contains `id` instead of `_id`. It's almost like the transform function is invoked once I do anything with the documents, but if I pass the documents directly as they arrive from the database, neither `toJSON` nor `toObject` is invoked.

Thanks in advance for your insights. :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Pratik149 yes I did, please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I also did exactly same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toJSON` and `toObject` methods won't work here because they don't apply to documents from an aggregation pipeline. Mongoose doesn't convert aggregation docs to mongoose docs, it returns the raw objects returned by the pipeline operation. I ultimately achieved this by adding pipeline stages to first add an `id` field with the same value as the `_id` field, then a second stage to remove the `_id` field. So essentially my pipeline became:

```js
        const pipeline = [
          {
            $match: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $or: [...],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
          // change the "_id" to "id"
          { $addFields: { id: '$_id' } },
          { $unset: ['_id'] },
          {
            $group: {
              _id : '$someProp',
              anotherProp: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
            },
          },
          { $sort: { date: -1 } },
          { $limit: 10 },
        ]
        const groupedDocs = await MyModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recast the raw objects into mongoose documents after getting them from the aggregate. You just need to transform them back one by one. They will then trigger the `toJSON` on return.

```
const document = Model.hydrate(rawObject);
```

Answer found here:
[Cast plain object to mongoose document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190478/cast-plain-object-to-mongoose-document)